Dynamic creation of QML Item from C++ causes ReferenceError
I have created a toast notification system and when I'm creating a toast object in C++ it creates the object, but gives a ReferenceError because of the "globals" which lives in the root of my main.qml. I was expecting this to work since I'm passing the valid QML engine to the QQmlComponent and that point the QML is up and running and has a proper context.
However, when I'm creating the toast object from QML's JavaScript, it is created without ReferenceError
Is it an ownership problem? BTW, I'm using Qt5.
ToastNotification.qml:
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5

Rectangle {
    id: toast

    property alias message: text.text

    implicitWidth: text.implicitWidth + Math.round(20)
    implicitHeight: text.implicitHeight + Math.round(20)

    // ReferenceError when ToastNotification.qml is created from C++
    color: globals.rsRed

    Text {
        id: text
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "I'm a toast notification... yay..."
    }    
}

This C++ code creates the toast:
QObject* ToastNotificationManager::createToast(const QString& message)
{
    QQmlComponent component(mQuickView->engine(), QUrl("qrc:/qml/ToastNotification.qml"), QQmlComponent::PreferSynchronous);

    QObject* toast = component.create();

    if (toast) {
        toast->setProperty("message", message);
        // I also set the visual parent of the toast using SetParentItem, but omitted from the example for the sake of simplicity
    }

    return toast;
}

My main QML code contains something like the followings. The toastButton is there for testing only. It will create the toast object without ReferenceError
Item {
    id: toastContainer
    QtObject {
        id: globals
        property color rsRed: "#BE1622"
    }
    Button {
        id: toastButton
        text: "Show toast"
        onClicked: {
            var comp = Qt.createComponent("qrc:/qml/ToastNotification.qml");
            var toast = comp.createObject(toastContainer);
            console.log(toast);
        }
    }
}


I can't tell from your code where createToast is called from, but I'm guessing it's not working because globals is out of scope from where you are using it. I recommend moving your globals to a separate singleton file. You should be able to reference that from anywhere.

I will check the singleton approach, thank you! Strange thing is if I create a Toast with the QML Javascript comp.createObject first and then using C++, there is no ReferenceError in C++. Also, I will check in Qt sources what is the difference between QML Component's createObject and QQmlComponent's create method.

When you create the component in main.qml, globals is also in main.qml, so it's in scope. So it makes sense that it would work there.

For now, I have figured out a trick where I use QMetaObject::invokeMethod to call a JS function that creates the toast and passes it back to C++ through a Q_INVOKABLE method. This way I have no ReferenceErrors. Also, it is more convinient to set position properties of the toast in QML instead of in the C++ code. Thank you for your answers!
